# Expected Iterator Design Pattern Behavior on extra next()

Tags: design-patterns

It seems to me that the Iterator design pattern should deliver a fatal error if it receives a `next()` command when `hasnext()` returns false. At least that's how I've implemented it in my SystemVerilog code.

Does a fatal error from an Iterator in this case violate some expectation of Iterator behavior?

Comment: Commonly you use the iterator on a while loop, so at the end I personally would expect the while loops ends properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is totally fine.

For e.g., even Java does the same:

> Throws:
>
> NoSuchElementException - if the iteration has no more elements

Check documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--).